# Slow VPN speed strongswan on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, pf

I put up a VPN server with strongswan 5.4.0 on FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p1 on a RaspberryPi 2. So far it works fine, but the speed is varying and also much slower than on Raspian which I used before.

Here is the configuration:

**/etc/rc.conf**

```
hostname="rpi2"
ifconfig_ue0="DHCP"
sshd_enable="YES"

powerd_enable="YES"

# Nice if you have a network, else annoying.
ntpd_enable="YES"

strongswan_enable="YES"

pf_enable="YES"
pf_rules="/etc/pf.conf"
pflog_enable="YES"
pflog_logfile="/var/log/pflog"  # where pflogd should store the logfile
gateway_enable="YES"            # Enable as LAN gateway

dnsmasq_enable="YES"
```

**/usr/local/etc/ipsec.conf**

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

 config setup
    charondebug="ike 2, knl 2, cfg 2, net 2, esp 2, dmn 2,  mgr 2"
    uniqueids = never


 conn ikev2
    left=%defaultroute
    leftid=example.com
    leftcert=VPN.crt
    leftsendcert = always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
#   leftfirewall=yes
    right=%any
    rightsourceip=10.0.0.1/24
    keyexchange=ikev2
    auto=add
    fragmentation=yes
    ike=aes128-sha256-ecp256!
    esp=aes128gcm16!
```

**/usr/local/etc/strongswan.conf**

```
# strongswan.conf - strongSwan configuration file
charon {
    dns1 = 192.168.1.58
    plugins {
            include strongswan.d/charon/*.conf
    }
}

include strongswan.d/*.conf
```

**/etc/pf.conf**

```
nat on ue0 from 10.0.0.1/24 to any -> (ue0)
```

The download speed on a connected machine is around 5 Mbit/s with Raspian it was around 20 Mbit/s. (The cpu usage is around 33 % on one core and memory usage is 44MB, so that should not be a obstacle to higher throughput)

My question I did I make some mistakes on my configuration? Want can I do to make it faster?

Also the VPN server sometimes makes XNU crash. Could this be a problem of the server?

**Edit:**

I just checked the connection speeds again. Download speed over VPN is around 5-8 Mbps and upload over VPN is around 13-18 Mbps. The internet connection on the raspberry should be ok, I checked it with wget which gives me around 6 MBps which is probably limited by the CPU core. On Debian both up- and download speed over VPN is around 20 Mbps. So there should be some improvements on FreeBSD? An additional question is: If I find out what the problem is, is there a way to take advantage of the multiple cores of the CPU to improve the speed even more?

**Edit2:**

I just checked the AES-GCM performance using OpenSSL 1.0.2j which gives me speeds around 7000kB/s. Maybe someone can explain me why I can or can not have those speeds at ESP?

Comment: 5Mbps seems more in line with what I get with my ARM A20...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro well on Raspbian I had 20  Mbps. What I forgot to mention os that the download speed is around 5-9 Mbps and upload is around 14-18 Mbps. My internet connection is 100/40 Mbps so it shouldn't affect these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked out Raspian again and I turned on parallel crypto. Now I get around 50 Mbps throughput. I think I can't achieve this with FreeBSD, so I will stay on Linux.